# How to add a check box on the lefthandside in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I have problem to design datagrid with checkbox in WPF and also how to get only check box values with gridview.

I am looking for something like above.[image]

Code snippet:

```
public payslip()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    SqlConnection con;
    public bool flag;
    string cn = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cc"];

    public void viewleave()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(cn);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("lvpayslip", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        lvpayslip.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;
        con.Close();
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        viewleave();
    }
   }
    }
```

I wanna checkbox columns like that please help me.....

Comment: Which part of "`GridViews` are not  `DataGridViews`" is so hard to understand?? __Do everbdoy a favour and stop confusing them!!__

Comment: See i am talking about datdgrid view.. the one we can get from toolbox..

Comment: There are NO `GridViews` in Winforms! Using the wrong names got you a WPF answer the [last time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752430/is-it-possible-to-populate-all-files-from-a-folder-to-grid-view)!

Comment: @TaW now is that Okay

Comment: please show the xaml code you have related to gridview

Comment: @YuliamChandra there is no Xaml code for this

Comment: Is this really WPF? How are you going to add the gridview to the window? add it programmatically? If so, show the code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a DataGridSelectColumn then you can try this in .xaml file

```
<DataGrid Name="lvpayslip">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}}">
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
                <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and in code behind

```
    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lvpayslip.SelectAll();
    }

    private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lvpayslip.SelectedItems.Clear();
    }
```